# Passing parameter in header tag

Tags: php, html

I am trying to pass value to the header.

Is there a way to pass parameter where it is directed to a new web page.

Below is my header code (it does not work), I would like to pass the parameter of "myCode" to the page.

```
header("Location: http://evon1991-z.comp.nus.edu.sg/Kxclusive/insertDetail.php".'$myCode');
```

How should I go about doing it?

Answer (score 3):

Variables don't expand inside single quotes. The result of string concatenation will look something like:

```
http://evon1991-z.comp.nus.edu.sg/Kxclusive/insertDetail.php$myCode
```

You need:

```
header("Location: http://evon1991-z.comp.nus.edu.sg/Kxclusive/insertDetail.php?param=$myCode");
```

..assuming `$myCode` is a plain value. In case  `$myCode` is a complete percent-encodeded query string format, prepend a `?` and append to the main URL.

Answer (score 2):

It depends how you want to pass it. If you want to do it via GET here's solution.

```
Header("Location: http://evon1991-z.comp.nus.edu.sg/Kxclusive/insertDetail.php?myCode=".$myCode);
```

Other method is for example $_SESSION

Moreover if you put variable into '' literal it wouldn't be parsed by PHP

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 header("Location: http://evon1991-z.comp.nus.edu.sg/Kxclusive/insertDetail.php?data=".$myCode);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is due to the fact that you include your variable in single quotes:

```
'$myCode'
```

This will actually add `$myCode` to the string, because variable parsing is not done inside single-quoted strings.  Instead, remove the quotes altogether and place it inside your string:

```
header("Location: http://evon1991-z.comp.nus.edu.sg/Kxclusive/insertDetail.php$myCode");
```

This assumes that `$myCode` contains the full string as you need to pass to append (i.e. in format `?param=value&param2=value2`